# How to safely redirect to the referrer page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http, redirect

I am using the following code to redirect to the referrer in my controller:

```
return Redirect(this.HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath);
```

During a scan with an application security tool it pointed out that the above code enables phishing attacks.

> A web application accepts a user-controlled input that specifies a link to an external site, and uses that link to generate a redirect. This enables phishing attacks.

Is there any way to safely redirected to the referrer?

Comment: Out of interest, why are you redirecting the user back to the page they came from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a general-purpose error, that is probably harmless in your case. The app sec tool doesn't realize that you're sending people back to the exact page they came from, but rather it sees the potential for you to do something like:

```
return Redirect(
    is_trusted_site( this.HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath )
    ? sensitiveURL
    : otherURL
);
```

If the redirected URL changed depending on the content of the `UrlReferrer`, then you could fall prey to [referrer spoofing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referrer_spoofing#Overview).

Just the same, if you want to fix the "error", you can perhaps use JavaScript's [`history.back()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.history).

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problems with this, given that what you actually want, is to redirect to whoever puts a link to your site on the whole Internet. You have no control over how the "referrer" ends up in the HTTP header. It might be legit, it might be forged. If this is OK with you, I see no problems.

Be aware that someone CAN use your site to redirect to anything, and that opens up for possible attacks. I.e., send an email that acutally links to your site, but in a query parameter specifies a phishing site.

What are you planning to use this for?